# Support of SSLParameters by SSLSocket, SSLServerSocket, SSLEngine and SSLContext

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, jsse

`SSLParameters` support the following properties (as per Spring notation): `cipherSuites`, `protocols`, `wantClientAuth`, `needClientAuth`, `algorithmConstraints`, `endpointIdentificationAlgorithm`, `serverNames`, `SNIMatchers`, `useCipherSuitesOrder`.

However, in the `SSL{Socket, ServerSocket, Engine}.setSSLParameters` it is apparent that only `cipherSuites`, `protocols`, `wantClientAuth`, `needClientAuth` are used. What's the rest of `SSLParameters` are for?

Are they just for custom heavyweight implementations such as HTTPS clients, and as such not used at all by JVM? Is the support for these features located elsewhere, if so, where? Is `useCipherSuitesOrder` supported by JVM, where? Is it actually a desired feature?

Another question is that `SSLParameters` has `protocols`, but they are applied to e.g. `SSLSocket` already created using `SSLContext`, which already has a single protocol chosen. In which contexts does this make sense? Can you pre-apply `SSLParameters` to `SSLContext`? Can you have widest possible `SSLContext` and then constrain it using `SSLParameters`? E.g. does it make sense to have SSLContext of protocol `"TLS"` and then use SSLParameters of protocols `{"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"}` to only have a subset of TLS cipher suites? Is "TLS" a superset of all "TLSv1.*x*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later I can answer my own question: Apparently, when you call `ctx.createSSLEngine()` an instance of vendor-specific `SSLEngine` will be returned, such as `sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl`, which will make more thorough use of passed `SSLParameters` by passing them to `sun.security.ssl.SSLConfiguration#setSSLParameters`.